# Recursive function for a specific tree

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am struggling with a very bad recursive function. I have the following array

```
$structure_array = array(

0 => array(
    'name' => 'Shop All',
    'children' => array( // this has 2 children
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'RC Something',
            'children' => array( // this only has 1 child
                0 => array(
                    'name' => 'Boats'
                )
            )
        ),
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'Something else'
        )
    )
)
);
```

And need to get this, out of it

```
// 0 => array(Shop ALl)
// 1 => array(Shop ALl, RC Something)
// 2 => array(Shop ALl, RC Something, 'Boats')
// 3 => array(Shop ALl, Something Else)
```

I can't figure out a proper way to do it. THe original code is broken, and the recursive function that was in use returned wrong results. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

edit: here is the original recursive one:

```
private function getNestedCats($cats, $names, &$results, $id_lang)
{
    foreach ($cats as $cat)
    {

    }

    // try to return a string with all subcats

    foreach ($cats as $cat)
    {
        if (isset($cat['children']) && is_array($cat['children']) && count($cat['children']) > 0)
        {
            if ($cat['is_root_category'] == 0)
                $names[] = $cat['name'];

            $this->getNestedCats($cat['children'], $names, $results, $id_lang);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($cat['is_root_category'] == 0)
                $names[] = $cat['name'];

            $results[] = $names;
            // array_pop($names);
        }
    }
}
```

I got rid of my first test, but basically I got rid of the reference parameter results and in the children if block, looped through children and appended the first key to $names. Then added $names to $results and returned that in the end.
It didn't work as I only got like shop all, shop all. 2 times Shop All, in the final array.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: it sound like a homework for us =)

Comment: What is your expected output? You want to just print `0 => array(Shop ALl)` etc. on screen or do you expect an array that you will be able to use later on?

Comment: I added the function. I need to get an array I can use later on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what about that?

```
global $solution;
$solution = array();
function fillSolution($key, $value, $prefix) {
    global $solution;
    if(is_string($key) && $key == "name") {
        if(empty(trim($prefix))) {
            $prefix .= "$value";
        } else {
            $prefix .= ", $value";           
        }
        array_push($solution, $prefix);
        return $prefix;
    } else { // $key is numeric or children and value is an array
        $p = $prefix;
        foreach($value as $k => $v) {
            $prefix = fillSolution($k, $v, $prefix);
        }
        return $p;
    }
}
fillSolution(0, $structure_array[0], '');

print_r($solution);

for($i=0; $i < count($solution); $i++) {
    echo "// $i => array($solution[$i])\n";
    // use </br> instead of \n for printing new line in html
}
```

This will print:

```
Array                                                                           
( 
    [1] => Shop All, RC Something                                               
    [2] => Shop All, RC Something, Boats                                        
    [3] => Shop All, Something else                                             
)                                                                               
// 0 => array(Shop All)                                                         
// 1 => array(Shop All, RC Something)                                           
// 2 => array(Shop All, RC Something, Boats)                                    
// 3 => array(Shop All, Something else)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much! The empty check was returning an error, but in any case I converted prefix into an array as that is what I need. You saved my day!